# Authenticating user against Windows cache when Active Directory is not available

Tags: vb6, active-directory

My application needs to authenticate a user against active directory and determine the list of groups the user is a member of. I've developed a VB6 app to do this and it works fine.

The customer has come back and said they need the app to authenticate users even if active directory is not available (machine off network), similar to how Windows will still allow a user to log on to a system if a machine is off the network, if they've logged onto the machine previously.

How do I go about accessing the cached user information in VB6? I'm currently user ADI and LDAP.

Comment: Can you provide the code you are using to authenticate the user?

Comment: We really need to see some code but if this is actually possible then I guess you need to be doing an LDAP query on the local machine instead of a Domain Controller